# Test async action creator

Tags: mocha.js, redux

Can you show me an example to how to test this action? I grab the action creator from [real-world](https://github.com/rackt/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world) redux example.

```
function fetchUser(login) {
  return {
    [CALL_API]: {
      types: [USER_REQUEST, USER_SUCCESS, USER_FAILURE],
      endpoint: `users/${login}`,
      schema: Schemas.USER
    }
  };
}
```

Sorry for my bad English ;(

Comment: What are you trying to test here?  This function simply returns an object. If you wanted to test if the action was dispatched, you'll need to test the `loadUser` below it with your own api testing middleware to make sure the action was actually dispatched.  However, that is trivial since you could extract that same information with a Logger.

Comment: Yes, I know, I'm just learning redux and unit tests, that's why I want to test everything :D. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @AlexBogoslovskiy check the git issue created on that subject: [example tests](https://github.com/rackt/redux/issues/788#issuecomment-142715764)

Answer (score 1):

Solution by @gaearon:

```
import { CALL_API } from '../middleware/api';
import { fetchUser } from '../actions';

expect(fetchUser('svnlto')[CALL_API].endpoint).toEqual('/users/svnlto');
```

for more detailed info check out the [github issue "example test"](https://github.com/rackt/redux/issues/788#issuecomment-142722793)

Answer (score 1):

There is now information on writing tests for async action creators using middleware [in the official documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html).